How to find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|x_n|}$ for a random Fibonacci sequence.
A friend of mine gave the following problem:
Let $x_0 = x_1 = 1$ and define for $n \geq 0$
$$x_{n+2} = \pm x_{n+1} \pm x_n,$$ where the two $\pm$ signs are chosen randomly, equiprobable and independent. Then with probability 1, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|x_n|} = 1.13198824...$$
I started to solve this by considering the ++ case. I did the following:
Since $$x_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\left[\phi^n - (\frac{1}{\phi } )^n\right],$$
where $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$ and $$|x_n| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\left(\phi^n + \frac{1}{\phi^n}\right),$$
we have from, $|a| -|b| \leq |a - b| \leq |a| + |b|,$
$$\left(\frac{\phi^n}{\sqrt 5}-\frac{1}{\sqrt 5 \phi ^n}\right)^{1/n} \leq |x_n|^{1/n} \leq \left(\frac{\phi^n}{\sqrt 5}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 5 \phi^n}\right)^{1/n}$$
or equivalently
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{\phi^{2n}}\right)^{1/n} \leq \frac{\sqrt[2n]{5} }{\phi}|x_n|^{1/n} \leq \left(1+ \frac{1}{\phi^{2n}}\right)^{1/n}.$$
When I take limits, I get $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|x_n|} = \phi$. Any hints on how to go about this and the other cases would be greatly appreciated.

What makes you think that this converges when randomly changing the recurrence relation. Also I think they mean that each step you choose new signs.

in the last step, you pulled a $\sqrt5$ out of the parentheses, but didn't take the $n$-th root of it. Correcting this, you get $\lim x_n^{1/n}=\phi$, which is also already clear from your first equation for $x_n$. But note that you haven't made any progress towards your problem, since the probability of only choosing $+$ in each step is $0$.

I'd have asked my friend about the existence of the limit but unfortunately, someone gave it to him too.@Vincent

I think the convergence is a consequence of the Fustenberg-Kesten theorem, see https://www.jstor.org/stable/2237962

Not really an answer, but here is at least some numerical data to inspire confidence in the claim.
As suggested in the comments, the signs should be chosen randomly each iteration and be i.i.d.

Figure: Simulation of 100000 sample trajectories for various $n$.
